# Slow find with including multiple associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In a Rails controller action I call

```
@grid = Grid.find(params[:id], :include => [:grid_properties, :grid_entities => [:entity => :properties]])
```

Unfortunately it takes really long. `Benchmark.realtime` (in development mode) tells me `1.8812830448150635`, so about 2 seconds (Rails 3.0.7, Postgres 8.4).

When turning on the SQL logging I get the following for this line of code:

```
Grid Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "grids".* FROM "grids" WHERE "grids"."id" = 2 LIMIT 1
GridProperty Load (2.5ms)  SELECT "grid_properties".* FROM "grid_properties" WHERE ("grid_properties".grid_id = 2) ORDER BY row_order
GridEntity Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "grid_entities".* FROM "grid_entities" WHERE ("grid_entities".grid_id = 2) ORDER BY row_order
Entity Load (3.0ms)  SELECT "entities".* FROM "entities" WHERE ("entities"."id" IN (28,7,3,6,25,11,2,12))
Property Load (6.4ms)  SELECT "properties".* FROM "properties" WHERE ("properties".entity_id IN (28,7,3,6,25,11,2,12))
```

Every database access seems to be in the low millisecond range. Why does it take so long in the end?

Comment: Is the `Benchmark.realtime` only for the queries or does it include the time required for rendering the partials and templates?

Comment: Just exactly around the above find. Nothing else included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the time is spent on creating the object by Ruby. How many Properties are in that Grid? The time of 'SELECT FROM properties' looks relatively high.

You could further investigate the problem, if you have some functions where you could place checkpoints - `logger.debug "CHECKPOINT: #{Time.now} #{caller(0).first}"`

Do you have any 'on_load' callbacks, maybe?

Comment: Around 50 properties per entity, but no on_load callbacks. Puh, thats pretty much time for creating some Ruby objects (but I don't have any comparison values). Maybe I should directly access the data without creating Ruby objects at all.

Comment: Direct access will be surely faster, but the code will be less readable (in most of cases). If you have good test coverage, then it should be safe. You may also want to measure the memory usage when loading this data. Maye this will show something interesting?

Comment: Nothing special with memory usage also. Every property contains just 5 string fields where each field contains mostly less than 50 chars. So I guess cause of the multiple associations it isn't a good use case for ActiveRecord. I will try accessing the data directly and see what difference it makes. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Another thing I just tried is to run the same thing in production mode. It is astonishing how much faster it is ... the whole request is done in about 300-500ms (with the same find above). So maybe I just stay with that find call and just fetch some coffee when reloading the page in dev mode ;-)